# How to pop up small window containing a variable in php by clicking a button

Tags: javascript, php, html, popupwindow

Say I have a string defined in php

```
 <php?  
     $string="value";
  ?>
```

How do I pop up the content of $string in a new small window by clicking a button?

Comment: Are you looking for [`alert()`](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp)?

Comment: Typo there... Remove the second "?"

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines:

```
   <?php
    $string="value";
    $link = "<button onclick='window.open(url?str=$string)'></button>     
    echo $link;
   ?>
```

In the specified url may be php file - write code like:

```
echo $_GET['str'];
```

Comment: Maybe my description is bad, I mean by clicking a button in current page then pop out a new window containing the value. @Sanjay Kumar N S

Comment: Check now. Edited the answer.

Comment: You may miss a quotation sign somewhere @Sanjay Kumar N S

Answer (score 0):

Popup windows should be considered deprecated because most browsers have them disabled by default. If your purpose is only to display a particular string, it would be much better to store it in your page's Javascript and use a modal instead.

If you must do it with PHP alone, then have another page (`string.php` or something), store the string there, and link to it from the button. There's no way to redirect to a page/location that doesn't exist, unless you are using Javascript.

**How to do it with Javascript**: The easiest way for someone who doesn't know JS would be to use jQuery, which is a library that makes a lot of functions available, and has a huge number of plugins written for it. I just did a search for "simplest jquery modal plugin" and found [this](https://github.com/kylefox/jquery-modal). There's also a page with example code. Basically, you would need to include the jquery library, and this jquery modal plugin, like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <!--add jQuery:-->
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

      <!-- save the modal script on your server and link to it -->
      <script src="/path/to/jquery.modal.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- all your page code -->

    <div id="ex1" style="display:none;">
        <p><?php echo $string?></p>
    </div>

    <!-- Button / link to open the modal -->
    <button><a href="#ex1" rel="modal:open">View String</a></button>

</body>
</html>
```

You can see the modal at work here: http://kylefox.ca/jquery-modal/examples/index.html

Comment: I can use Javascript but don't know how to do it. @Sidd